# How can I get Country and Click ID (fbclid) to appear in the Advanced matching parameters of Browser test events?

Tags: facebook-pixel

I use both Facebook Pixel and the Conversions API to send events on both front and back ends (which get deduplicated by the Event IDs they share). I've noticed that Country and Click ID show in the **User Data Keys** on server events, but are missing from the corresponding **Advanced matching parameters** on browser events.

To reduce the surface area of this problem, I made a new Pixel and coded up a page that, on each load, initializes that Pixel with user data of a `city` and a `country` and tracks a PageView. When I refresh this site, I can see the city (hashed), country (hashed), and click ID (when provided) in the request to Facebook. But again, in the Test Events, I'm told that I sent a City but no Country or Click ID.

Does Meta just not bother showing those in browser events?